# Use object instead of array in datatables

Tags: datatables

When using datatables, I get 'no data available in table' when using an object instead of array:

```
var data1 =
{
    "status": "success",
    "districts": {
        "1": {
            "district_number": "1",
            "district_name": "district one"
        },
        "2": {
            "district_number": "2",
            "district_name": "district two"
        }
    },
    "time": "1.109s"
};

var table1 = jQuery("#data_table1").DataTable({
    "data": data1.districts,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "district_number" },
        { "mData": "district_name" }    
    ]
});
```

I can get an array to display in a datatable using mData as follows:

```
var data2 =
{
    "status": "success",
    "districts": [
        {
            "district_number": "1",
            "district_name": "district one"
        },
        {
            "district_number": "2",
            "district_name": "district two"
        }
    ],
    "time": "1.109s"
};

var table2 = jQuery("#data_table2").DataTable({
    "data": data2.districts,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "district_number" },
        { "mData": "district_name" }    
    ]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w93gubLv/

Is there a way to get datatables to utilize the object in the original format, or must I convert the object to an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to convert one format to another, for example:

```js
function formatData(data){
   var result = [];
   for(prop in data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
         result.push( data[prop] );
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

You can then later use it to pass data to jQuery DataTables as shown below.

```
var table1 = jQuery("#data_table1").DataTable({
    "data": formatData(data1.districts),
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "district_number" },
        { "mData": "district_name" }    
    ]
});
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w93gubLv/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew that an array works... I'm asking if an datatables can accept the native object.

Comment: @FishBulbX, it accepts array of arrays or array of objects. The solution in your case is to convert object into array of objects.